# Binding failures when adding another property

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a main view that binds to subviews like this (the backing property is of type `object`):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding WalletsView}"/>
```

Now, I've added another property to the corresponding viewmodel, namely

```
public SmartObservableCollection<Selectable<Type>> PriceGrabbers {get; private set;}
```

where `SmartObservableCollection` is derived from `ObservableCollection` to make multithreaded updates easier.

Now I get a lot of binding errors (in fact, **all** bindings in the sub viewmodels run through the debug window) like this (interestingly, if I remove the `PriceGrabbers` property again, all errors disappear):

> > System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OverviewHidden' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=30986197)'. BindingExpression:Path=OverviewHidden; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=30986197); target element is 'ColumnDefinition' (HashCode=22768693); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

So the binding engine apperently tries to find any and all bindings on the main viewmodel.
The bindings work perfectly fine. While this is okay, I'd rather have errors go away. Did anybody of you already encounter this problem, and if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Does the MainWindowViewModel have a property named OverviewHidden?

Comment: No, it doesn't. All binding failures are coming from the sub views. the MainViewModel does two things: a) provides the main menu b) puts all other views in a tab control. So apperently the subviews are trying to use the wrong ViewModel as DataContext first. The bindings work fine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with WPF but with my usage of MEF as composition container. The property modifies the import order of classes and the ViewModel coresponding to MainWIndow is assigned to all Views first, after which the correct one is assigned. When the data context is refreshed, all bindings are renewed, thus the application works.

**edit** and now I found the complete reason for it.

`SmartObservableCollection` takes an `Action<Action>>` parameter to execute on `CollectionChanged` events, this is needed due to most of my collections getting updated in a multithreaded manner, but the events have to be executed in the GUI thread, otherwise you will get an exception.

For this, my Views expose `Dispatcher.Invoke()` and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` as methods, which I then supply to the collection.

At startup, the DataContexts are assigned in the base class `ViewModel` by the following lines:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
{
    view.DataContext = this;
});
```

Who has an idea already?

The reason for this hickup was the simple fact I supplied the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method instead of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to the collection. By doing this (and the fact it was used in the `MainWindowViewModel`), it got executed before **any** `DataContexts` got assigned to other `ViewModels`.

Now, the next step occurs - the WPF engine tries to bind to the data in the sub views. As `DataContext` is `null`, the binding engine walks up the visual tree until it finds a set DataContext, in this case the first set DataContext is in `MainWindowView`, and it is `MainWindowViewModel`. Now, after the collection finished, all other actions get called and the DataContexts are assigned appropiately, thus reexecuting the binding engine which finds a non-null DataContext on the sub views and binds correctly.